# is it possible to send very big data over UDP?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, tcp

I want to send very big data over UDP.
I know that I can send 64K ( 64* 1024 bytes ) over UDP and I will have the fragmentation that supported by the UDP protocol.
But If I have more then 64K data to send ... how can I send it ?

I know that I can take this big data => convert it to byte array and divided this byte array into smaller parts ( of 64K ) and send it as single package ... and send all the packages using this way.

But is there any way to do it without divided it by myself ?
is it possible to have same using the build-in ( ip layer ) UDP/TCP fragmentation or I missing something ?

Comment: You can use TFTP if you want to stick to UDP or FTP if you are ok with TCP. Reading about how TFTP works is also a good idea. It acks per 2k or something and is able to transfer big files like that.

Comment: btw fragmentation is done at IP layer not at UDP layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I know that I can send 64K ( 64* 1024 bytes ) over UDP

No you can't. The absolute maximum size of a UDP datagram payload is 65507 bytes.

The generally accepted *practical* limit is 534 bytes.

Quite a difference.

> and I will have the fragmentation that supported by the UDP protocol.

Fragmentation is not supported by the UDP protocol. It is supported by the ***IP*** protocol. If you're lucky enough that a fragmented datagram's fragments all arrive, IP will reassemble it and pass it to UDP. If not, not. UDP itself play no part in this process whatsoever.

> But If I have more then 64K data to send ... how can I send it ?

A piece at a time, with sequence numbering, ACK- or NACK-based protocol, duplicate rejection, resequencing, reassembly, pacing, exponential backoff, ... In other words, TCP.

Comment: @keyser I know that's a joke, but for clarity, and so as not to mislead future readers, my last sentence shows exactly how to do exactly that.